# How can I change this HAML format to normal CSS style?

Tags: css, haml

I'm very new to CSS.
I was look at website that says that I should code something like this.
But I have to change it to CSS style.  But I don't know how.

```
ul.ui-complete
  li
    :display none
  li.ui-menu-item
    :display block
```

Can anyone show me how this should be in CSS style?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.ui-complete li {
     display: none;
}
ul.ui-complete li.ui-menu-item{
     display: block;
}
```